# How do you set Tasks in the Editor?

Tags: arma-3

I am creating a mission in the editor and I could not find any information about how Tasks are set in the editor.

How do you define a task in the editor that the player can choose to complete and how do you set a marker for that Task that is visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend the video-tutorials by jester. He's explaining the whole editor and has an episode for Tasks. It helped me a lot in building missions!

Here is the playlist with every tutorial in it:
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmfRxJX4Bs7FkhsducKrEmH5TBphUYzJV